# How to use group by with null values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL query which results as

```
personCount toatlMinute     Meal    QPWaiting       NoOfCR  CRNo
0           2               NULL    NULL            NULL    NULL
1           7               NULL    NULL            NULL    NULL
2           8               NULL    NULL            NULL    NULL
3           16              NULL    NULL            NULL    NULL
4           128             NULL    NULL            NULL    NULL
0           NULL            NULL    14              2       5555, 6666
3           NULL            NULL    NULL            NULL    NULL
4           NULL            NULL    NULL            NULL    NULL
2           NULL            NULL    14              2       5555, 6666
3           NULL            NULL    14              2       5555, 6666
4           NULL            NULL    14              2       5555, 6666
0           NULL            2       NULL            NULL    NULL
```

Now I want to use group by 1st column (`personcount`) and want to sum 2nd and 3rd column
but don't want to sum 4th, 5th and 6th column. But output should show all data in one for unique person count.

```
SELECT
    personCount,
    SUM(toatlMinute) toatlMinute,
    SUM(Meal) Meal,
    QPWaiting,
    NoOfNCR AS NoOfCR,
    NCRNo AS CRNo 
FROM 
    @OperatorData
GROUP BY
    personCount, QPWaiting, NoOfNCR, NCRNo
```

and it gives output as

```
personCount toatlMinute Meal    QPWaiting   NoOfCR  CRNo
0   2   2   NULL    NULL    NULL
0   NULL    NULL    14  2    5555, 6666
1   7   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2   8   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2   NULL    NULL    14  2    5555, 6666
3   16  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
3   NULL    NULL    14  2    5555, 6666
4   128 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
4   NULL    NULL    14  2    5555, 6666
```

A you can see there are two rows for 0 person count. However I want only one row.

How can get this output? Kindly advise

Comment: NULL is not equal with any value. Thus it doesn't make sense to be "collapsed" with any value. *However,* if you remove those columns from a group-by and use an appropriate *aggregate* function, then you should achieve your desired results .. e.g. `MAX({NULL,5555}) -> 5555`.

Comment: Why do you want one row for person 0, but not for 2 or 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get values from the last three columns, so the `NULL` values go away, then use `max()` or `min()`:

```
SELECT personCount, SUM(toatlMinute) as toatlMinute, SUM(Meal) as Meal,
       max(QPWaiting) as QPWaiting, max(NoOfNCR) AS NoOfCR, max(NCRNo) AS CRNo 
FROM  @OperatorData
GROUP BY personCount;
```

Comment: You should realize that while Gordon's solution will give you one row for each personCount value, the resulting values in the QPWaiting, NoOfCR, and CRNo columns may not all come from the same row of the original table.

One problem with your question is that you are asking for one result for each personCount value, but you are not explaining what values you want to see in the rightmost columns, specifically if they differ among the original rows for a particular personCount.